# Does it make any sense trying to compile .NET Core CLR for Windows CE?

Tags: .net-core, cross-platform, windows-ce

We're in the unfortunate situation of still having to support a Windows CE based device (ARMV7 architecture). We're continuously running into problems regarding the limited functionality of .NET Compact framework (no security libraries, very limited asynchronous support, ...). Since the .NET Core CLR has been compiled for multiple platforms, including ARM-based platform, the idea of trying to compile it for Windows CE as well came up. I invested about a day to see how far I'd get, however I'm not the most experienced CMake user.

I couldn't find any hint on the internet whether someone ever tried, so... Is there a basic possibility of succeeding in doing so or are there limitations I do not yet see which make getting a working version highly improbable?

Comment: In other way u can install Quemu and then in vm install minimal Linux to run .Net Core app. I know, it's bad but hey - It can work

Comment: Say you have CoreCLR compiled and working. Where will you go next? Are you planning on compiling CoreFX as well, then? Keep in mind there isn a good story right on on compiling .NET Core end-to-end on a new platform. See https://github.com/dotnet/source-build/issues/192

Comment: @J.Doe Unfortunately, I doubt we'll get the required performance we're looking for that way. ;)

Comment: @omajid Yes, the consequence would be to compile CoreFX as well. Thanks a lot for the link!

Comment: If you want to build everything on a new platform, source-build is what you probably want to use. Please file issues and submit patches as you run into bugs!

Comment: I'd also like to know if there is a workable solution as we also have to target devices running Windows CE 3.9, and wonder if there is a route to dot net core.

@illoOminated - How have you got on with this?

Comment: @Dib Since time is really of the matter for us at the moment, I have not yet had any time to investigate this issue any further. However, I plan to acquire a personal Windows CE device soon, since I'd like to further investigate the possibilities privately. I will definitely get back to this question as soon as I have anything to show.

Comment: @illoOminated - Well I'd definitely be interested if you do, as I am sure others around the world will also. So please do come back and add another comment if you find a reasonably straight forward solution.

Comment: Also love to hear about any developments on this front.

Comment: I'm in a similar situation.  But I'm investigating golang instead of .net